# Как скачать страницу по url python?

Tags: html

Задача такая. Есть url, нужно скачать html страницу, но на сайте используется https и javascript. Делал с помощью lxml и других библиотек, в итоге пустая страница качается. Подскажите, что использовать, желательно на python. Но можно и c++ или c#, или java. Что для этой задачи лучше?

Comment: urllib2, если я не путаю, прекрасно работает с https.

Comment: Она не работает с javascript, к сожалению

Comment: Вам нужно скачать с URLа некий файл? Вы его скачаете. JS тут не при чем.

Comment: Но javascript дополняет страницу данным, которые мне и нужны

Comment: Значит заголовок не совсем корректен) Возможно, стоит покопать в сторону phantomjs

Comment: Тогда это не просто скачать, а еще и проэмулировать работу браузера. Насколько я знаю, нет ни одного интерпретатора JS на Питоне. Возможно, PhantomJS вам поможет.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов интерпретаторы на JS на Питоне есть (как простые обёртки над каким-нибудь v8 или duktape, так и прям на чистом питоне вроде js2py), но, правда, браузерного окружения они не предоставляют и в данном вопросе не помогут

Comment: @andreymal ну обертки не считаются. А вот про js2py не слышал даже. DOM'а у него нет, вы говорите?